# Bootstrap Mobile Menu Stays Open

Tags: navbar

I have a One Page template, that uses 'scroll-to' nav class. Everything works, but the mobile menu won't close, and the content appears behind the menu.

If I add … data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in" to the links … the menu will close, but I lose the 'scroll-to' function.

Does anybody know how I can combine the 'scroll-to' CLASS and the data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".in"?

Nothing I've tried has worked.

This is the current nab menu … thanks for looking!

```
<!-- Navigation Top start -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-hidden navigation-top" id="navigation-top-1"
    role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
       <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
       <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                   data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <!-- Logo start -->
           <a class="navbar-brand scroll-to" href="#home">
               <span class="va-helper"></span>
               <img src="img/nav-logo-mint1.png"/>
           </a>
           <!-- Logo end -->
       </div>

       <!-- Nav-Links start -->
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
           <ul style="padding-top:15px;" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
               <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="scroll-to">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#about-us" class="scroll-to">About Us</a></li>
               <li><a href="#surfing-lessons" class="scroll-to">Surfing Lessons</a></li>
              <li><a href="#rentals" class="scroll-to">Rentals</a></li>
               <li><a href="#team" class="scroll-to">Team</a></li>
               <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll-to">Contact</a></li>
                                           <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-success show-appointment-modal"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> Book A Lesson</a></li>

           </ul>
       </div>
       <!-- Nav-Links end -->
   </div>
</nav>
<!-- Navigation Top end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

your HTML menu code perfect. But I think, you have to scroll sections by using JQuery. try this

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  // jQuery for page scrolling
    $('a.scroll-to').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)
        }, 1000);
         event.preventDefault();
    });
  
});
```

```css
.sample-nav{
  width:100%;
  height:35px; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; background:#000;
}

.sample-nav a{color:#fff;
-webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;}

.menu-bg{
background-color:red;
  width:100%; height:600px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
#menu2{background-color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
  <body>
    
    <div class="sample-nav">
      <a class="scroll-to" href="#menu1">Menu1</a>
    <a class="scroll-to" href="#menu2">Menu2</a>
      </div>
    
    
    
    
    <div class="menu-bg" id="menu1"></div>
    <div class="menu-bg" id="menu2"></div>
    
    
    
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

The mobile navigation stays opened when a link is clicked. The content appears behind the navigation.

This only happens on on mobile namely iPhone … no issues on a desktop computer.

Thanks